# Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. CORS vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I know that question is already asked, and I asked again because I dont know if active cors=true or cors="Anonymous", like the upvote aswers generate some kind of vulnerability on my program/system, and if that happens what would be the solution.
Beforehand thank you very much